# Let's get critical: Apr 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Board & Card Games Stack Exchange](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- ["Whenever you draw a card" - does that include the beginning of each turn?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23324/whenever-you-draw-a-card-does-that-include-the-beginning-of-each-turn)

**Net Score: 13** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How many Tokens does Sidisi, the Brood Tyrant make when multiple creature cards enter the graveyard simultaneously?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23060/how-many-tokens-does-sidisi-the-brood-tyrant-make-when-multiple-creature-cards)

**Net Score: 13** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does Seeds of Strength trigger Heroic three times?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23053/does-seeds-of-strength-trigger-heroic-three-times)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Will Enduring Ideal and Dovescape played together leave Enduring Ideal countered?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23313/will-enduring-ideal-and-dovescape-played-together-leave-enduring-ideal-countered)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [When does "at the beginning of the next end step" trigger?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23377/when-does-at-the-beginning-of-the-next-end-step-trigger)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [BSG Exodus: What happens with a damaged base star on launch raiders?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23221/bsg-exodus-what-happens-with-a-damaged-base-star-on-launch-raiders)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Navigator Role ability](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23383/navigator-role-ability)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is it better to close gates or save up clue tokens to seal them?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23076/is-it-better-to-close-gates-or-save-up-clue-tokens-to-seal-them)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Can a Rummikub tile be moved](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23354/can-a-rummikub-tile-be-moved)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Deriving statistics from original card games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23045/deriving-statistics-from-original-card-games)

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 7)

---